# Hide recipient's email in a form from spammers

Tags: forms

I have a form the content of which is sent to my email using the line below, once the user clicks the submit button:

```
<input id="to" name="to" type="hidden" value="iram@example.com" />
```

and I have a mail.jsp file that handles the form. As you notice, I have set the input type as hidden, but I heard that the email can still be seen/used by spammers to send spam mails to others. If this is so, how can I do this to avoid spamming problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you including your email in jsp? why can't it be on the server side?

Comment: The email is in the HTML form, and the jsp only handles the form. You mean have the email somewhere else on the server side rather than in the form?

Comment: are you taking this email from the user?

Comment: No, that is the recipient's email. Basically I want to hide the recipient's email from spammers.

Comment: then there is no need to pass it as a hidden parameter.you keep it in a variable on the server side. That way you don't have to worry about your email getting exposed

Comment: I managed to do it like that; I have the recipient email as a variable on the server side in the JSP code and no email defined in the form. That should do the trick, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- As you mentioned the form data is to be sent to a fixed e-Mail ID there is no need to pass it as a hidden parameter in the form.
- The jsp source is visible to all (users of the website) hence it would be a better choice to keep it on the server side hard-coded in the servlet (visible only to developer) that is responsible for sending the mail.

  UPDATE:
- Following the MVC architecture jsps should only be used for presentation and not for the logic implementation (avoid scriptlets).
- The business logic needs to be taken care of by servlets and beans present on the server side.

Comment: The jsp source I mentioned is only responsible for sending the email and redirecting the user to a separate 'thank you' page. It doesn't display any feedback to the users. Is it still a problem?

Comment: if the user is redirected to this jsp after form submission the it is a server side jsp page. in that case it is ok but you should have your logic in the servlets and jsps should be used only for presentation

Comment: Right. User is redirected to the jsp after form submission. Actually when I first made the jsp file, I didn't think about the spam problem and handled all my forms with JSP, but now it is kinda late to redo everything from scratch. Thanks anyway for your help and recommendations.

Comment: By the way, I can see the edit link under your answer active and I can edit your answer. Is this some kind on bug on stackoverflow's site?

Comment: if you edit the answer it will be kept in a queue for review..see the link next to your badges

Comment: You can easily switch to servlets because your java code (logic) will remain the same